# SSIS Oracle table w/BLOBs XML to SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, xml, oracle, ssis, blob

We have an Oracle table that contains archived data in the table format:

`BLOB | BLOBID`

Each BLOB is an XML file that contains all the business objects we need.

Every BLOB needs to be read, the XML parsed and put into 1 SQL Server table that will hold all data.

The table has 5 columns `R | S | T | D | BLOBID`

Sample XML derived from BLOB:

```
<N>
  <E>
    <R>33</R>
    <S>1</S>
    <T>2012-01-25T09:48:43.213</T>
    <D>6.9534619e+003</D>
  </E>
  <E>
    <R>33</R>
    <S>1</S>
    <T>2012-01-25T09:48:45.227</T>
    <D>1.1085871e+004</D>
  </E>
  <E>
    <R>33</R>
    <S>1</S>
    <T>2012-01-25T09:48:47.227</T>
    <D>1.1561764e+004</D>
  </E>
</N>
```

There are a few million BLOBs and we want to avoid copying all the data over as an XML column then to a table, instead we want to go BLOB to table in one step.

What is the best approach to doing this with SSIS/SQL Server?

The code below almost does what we are looking for but only in Oracle Developer and only for one BLOB:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.FF';
SELECT b.BLOBID, a.R as R, a.S as S, a.T as T, cast(a.D AS float(23)) as D
FROM XMLTABLE('/N/E' PASSING
    (SELECT xmltype.createxml(BLOB, NLS_CHARSET_ID('UTF16'), null)
    FROM CLOUD --Oracle BLOB Cloud
    WHERE BLOBID = 23321835)
    COLUMNS
    R int PATH 'R',
    S int PATH 'S',
    T TIMESTAMP(3) PATH 'T',
    D VARCHAR(23) PATH 'D'
    ) a
```

Removing `WHERE BLOBID = 23321835` gives the following error `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row` since there are millions of BLOBS. Even so is there a way to run this through SSIS? Adding the SQL to the OLE DB Source did not work for pulling the data from Oracle even for 1 BLOB and would result in errors.

Using SQL Server 2012 and Oracle 10g

**To summarize, how would we go from a Oracle BLOB containing XML to SQL Server table with business objects derived from XML with SSIS?**

I'm new to working with Oracle, any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

I was able to get some of my code to work in SSIS by modifying the Oracle Source in SSIS to use the SQL command code above minus the first line,

```
 ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.FF';
```

SSIS doesn't like this line.

Error message with the ALTER SESSION line above included:

[No column information was returned by the SQL Command](http://s3.postimg.org/d0mmjg54j/ssis_error.png)

Would there be another way to format the date without losing data? I'll try experimenting more, possible using varchar(23) for the date instead of timestamp.

Comment: You could try extending that code to use some kind of cursor and pipe it back, but you'll probably have difficulties with SQL understanding he meta data. The next option would be using a cursor to feed that into an Oracle table then read the oracle table directly. Will you be doing this repeatedly or is it a one off? The main challenge is getting SSIS to recognise the metadata.

Comment: and another option is to use a for each loop in SSIS to read it row by row but this would be very slow.

Comment: This will be repeatedly done to fetch archived data. That is what I was thinking too about using the above code with a cursor to iterate though all the BLOBs but I can't get that code to work in SSIS, only works in an Oracle environment. I have been able go from an Oracle BLOB to a XML table on SQL Server then parsed the XML to the correctly formatted SQL table with SSIS. But the goal is to avoid using an intermediate table to hold the XML, if this is possible.

Comment: So what are your limitations here? Can you create a package or stored procedure on the Oracle side? If you want you couldtry to troubleshoot the 
"can't get that code to work in SSIS" part. Basically if you have that code working and SSIS recognising the metadata then that's a really good start.

Comment: I can create a stored procedure on the Oracle side if needed and call it through the SSIS package. The real limitation is to avoid creating additional tables and it needs to be fast since a few million BLOBs could be pulled. I did get the most of above code to finally work in SSIS, the first line was the issue. But now I have to figure out how to format the date correctly, but you are right I am off to a good start! Just have to figure out how to fix the date and setup a cursor to iterate though the BLOBs.

Comment: With regards to formatting date. Yes you can send it through as a VARCHAR and cast it to a date using a derived column trasformation. You'll probably have speed issues though. Having a staging table (ELT) is usually faster that doing in-stream transformations (ETL)